# How to model multiple inputs to single output in classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, linear-regression, feature-selection

**Purpose:**

I am trying to build a model to classify multiple inputs to a single output class, which is something like this:

> {x_i1, x_i2, x_i3, ..., x_i16} (features) to y_i (class)

I am using a SVM to make the classification, but the 0/1-loss was bad (half of the data a misclassified), which leads me to the conclusion that the data might be non-linear. This is why I played around with polynomial basis function. I transformed each coefficient such that I get any combinations of polynomials up to degree 4, in the hope that my features are linear in the transformed space. my new transformed input looks like this:

> {x_i1, ..., x_i16, x_i1^2, ..., x_i16^2, ... x_i1^4, ..., x_i16^4, x_i1^3, ..., x_i16^3, x_i1*x_i2, ...}

The loss was minimized but still not quite where I want to go. Since with the number of polynomial degree the chance of overfitting rises, i added regularization in order to counter balance that. I also added a forward greedy algorithm in order to pick up the coefficients which leads to minimal cross-validation error, but with no great improvement.

**Question:**

Is there a systematic way to figure out which transform leads to linear feature behaviour in the transformed space? Seems little odd to me that I have to try out every polynomial until it "fits". Are there perhaps better basis functions except polynomials? I understand that in low dimensional feature space, one can simply plot the data out and estimate the transform visually, but how can I do it in high dimensional space?

Maybe a little off topic but I also informed myself about PCA in order to throw away the components which doesnt provide much informations in the first place. Is this worth a try?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try other kernel functions such as RBF other than linear and polynomial? Since different dataset may have different characteristics, some kernel functions may work better than others do, especially in non-linear cases.

I don't know which tools you are using, but the following one also provides a guide for beginners on how to build SVM models:

https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/

It is always a good idea to have a feature selection step first, especially for high-dimensional data. Those noisy or irrelevant features should be taken away, leading to a better performance and higher efficiency.

Comment: A kernelized perceptron gives me better classification in the one-vs-all case, but how do I calculate the confidence in the overall classification?